# ORM Comparison Bulk and Batch operation overview

Tags: c#, .net, orm, comparison

There are many articles [about the pro's and con's of ORMs](http://ormeter.net/) [and comparison matrices](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AtMUz5Z1OXjudEpWc3pvdWtRZlFrUVM4WVZlOWJFQnc&hl=en&output=html) 

And it looks like [*DataObjects.Net*](http://dataobjects.net/)  is wining the competition(for now)

Test categories are usually performance, LINQ support, Caching, Collection support ... 
Now my question is, if you have to use bulk operation(end of day operations) and batch support(DB job scheduling) which of the ORMSs will be your choose?

Any practical experiment will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow. Asking for web resources in this manner is considered not-constructive here, as detailed in [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: The benchmarks in the linked article are nearly 3 years old!

Comment: @ qujck: It will be highly apperciated if you may introduce new reliable ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that ORM tools are not designed for large batches of queries. Some can handle this acceptably (like NHibernate for example in some cases), but it depends. I think you are looking at the wrong tool for the job.